# Установка NodeJs

Tags: linux, apache, node.js

После установки `NodeJs`, можно как то сделать что бы переходя на доменное имя не надо было перед этим выполнять такую команду в терминале node `app.js`.

Тоесть мы имеем сервер `Apache`, одно доменное имя (уже привязанное, работает) и установленный `NodeJs`. Естественно если в консоли перейти в папку с сайтом и запустить `node app.js` то перейдя по адресу `http://domain.com:3000` вы увидим работу нашего сайта, так как сделать что бы `NodeJs` сам ссылался на определнный порт, без всякого запуска из консоли ?

**Так как овет найден, тогда немного глуповатый но мне не понятный вопрос, какой лучше всего использовать порт, по всем примерам в app.js указан 3000, может это только для примера, или же 3000 порт тоже нормально ?**

Comment: Ваш вопрос равносилен этому: "Как заставить сайт открываться по адресу http://domain.com:3000, не запустив Apache?"

Nodejs это серверная платформа, в целом, как и Apache. Чтобы сайт работал вам необходимо запускать сервер

Comment: Может перефразирую вопрос, как демонизировать процесс запуска ? Если запустить приложение в терминале (node app.js) то этот процесс должен быть всегда в рабочем состоянии, и естественно что бы что то сделать придется его вырубать, так вот как сделать что бы этот процесс сам работал при запуске apache ?

Comment: Нашел такой вариант запуска
sudo nohup node /home/nodeProject/myProject/app.js &

Comment: Считаю довлно таки хорошим решением окозалось использование пакета forever
`$npm install forever -g`
`$forever start app.js`
https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever

Comment: Все БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО !!! 
Вопрос можно закрывать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Среди [10 шагов к Nodejs нирване](http://qzaidi.github.io/2013/05/14/node-in-production/) упоминают скрипт [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) для «тёплого лампового» линуксового [пере]запуска сервера.

Как другой вариант можно использовать [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) для контроля за тем, что процесс не сдох «внезапно», что он действительно работает, а не просто «висит», авто-перезапуска его в случае конфуза, и для запуска при включении системы.

Тут вот [рассматривают](http://blog.hemantthorat.com/monitoring-node-js-with-monit-upstart-and-forever-js/#sthash.Srpi6oys.dpbs) upstart, monit и еще forever.js как альтернативу monit'у.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, это оно же, или это уже другой minit ?

https://github.com/nicokaiser/node-monit

Comment: мне больше supervisor нравится, в 3й версии вообще лапочка.

Comment: @kostya да, monit тот же.

@eicto спасибо, я пока не пробовал [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), надо бы ознакомиться.

Comment: 1. Не нашел в доках monit описание что он сам перезапускается
2. Если supervisor это - https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor то опционально не лучше чем forever, или может я и ошибаюсь

Comment: не, это supervisord - на питоне написано, его питонщики любят, но он себя хорошо показал и для удержания node активным и для gearmand задач - из фич:

 * можно заказать количество активных инстансов
 * можно указать юзера
 * минимальное время работы  и перезапусков (скажем 10 раз грохнулось не проработав и секунды - не запускаем 10 мин, я не юзаю но полезно иногда)

Comment: Спасибо, уже интересно )

Comment: Тогда такой вопросик, есть разница на каком порту я запущу, на 3000 или 1137 например ?

Comment: вообще нет разницы, но для привилегированных портов (<1024) нужно устраивать su внутри приложения, но я бы в таком случае вообще на unix socket вешал и nginx бы подключался.